# How do I get Messages to appear in the Notification Center?

Tags: ios, notifications

I've configured Notifications to display Messages in the Notification Center, but no messages ever appear there.

[image]

Is there another setting that I'm missing? Are only certain kinds of messages displayed in the Notification Center?

Comment: Notification Center -> On is all you have to do. What is happening when you receive a message? A screenshot of that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a (temporary) bug that sometimes happened shortly after an app is first configured for Notification Center. The settings indicated in the original question should be sufficient to get messages to appear in Notification Center.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, actually there are two things to check:

- First "View in Lock Screen" must be ON
- And Messages must be under "In Notification Center"

[image: turn on 'View in Lock Screen'][image: in Notification Center]

If you do these, your messages will be displayed in both Notification Center and the Lock Screen.

Comment: I don't want to see them in the Lock Screen.

Comment: then you skip the first part. I guess that was an overshare.